How do you solve for x in $\frac{\log(x+1000)-\log(x+1)}{\log(x+100)-\log(x+1)}=c$?
I need to solve for $x$ in the following equation:
$$
\frac{\log(x+1000)-\log(x+1)}{\log(x+100)-\log(x+1)}=c
$$
$c$ is a known constant. I've tried replacing $x+1$ for $s$, a bunch of log identities and raising to a power but I'm not getting any closer. Wolfram doesn't know either. Any ideas? Graph of function

Large or small $c$ ?

This does not seem to have a closed form solution. YOu can only hope for approximations or iterative procedures. And for that you need to know the range (value of $c$?)

I think you can only get a solution analytically if c=1 (I can write it if you want). For other values of c, numerical methods should be used, I would say.

Also, clarify is the log is natural or decimal

@leonbloy. Do you think it matters ?

Of course not, my bad

Instead of $\log(x+1000) - \log(x+1)$, shouldn't it be $\log(x+1000) - \log(x+10)$?

This requires solving $(1–\frac{999}{x+1000})(1+\frac{99}{x+1})^c=1$

I just thought of an approach, which I am not sure if it works but I am providing details.
We have to solve for x in the given equation, c being a known constant.
$\frac{\log(x+1000)-log(x+1)}{log(x+100)-log(x+1)} =c$
Since, $\log a - \log b= log(a/b)$,
$\Rightarrow \frac{\log\left(\frac{x+1000}{x+1}\right)}{\log\left(\frac{x+100}{x+1}\right)} = c$
$\Rightarrow \log\left(\frac{x+1000}{x+1}\right) = c \cdot \log\left(\frac{x+100}{x+1}\right)
$
Now, we know, $ c\ .log( a) = \log(a^c)$,so the equation becomes,
$\Rightarrow \log\left(\frac{x+1000}{x+1}\right) = \log\left(\left(\frac{x+100}{x+1}\right)^c\right)$
Eliminating log on both sides we get,
$\Rightarrow \frac{x+1000}{x+1} = \left(\frac{x+100}{x+1}\right)^c$
Consider the substitution, $y=x+1,$
So the equation becomes,
$\Rightarrow \frac{y+999}{y}=\left(\frac{y+99}{y}\right)^c$
As ,$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^c = \frac{a^c}{b^c}$,
$\Rightarrow \frac{y+999}{y} = \left(\frac{(y+99)^c}{y^c}\right)$
$\Rightarrow (y+999). \ y^c=(y+99)^c . \ y$
$\Rightarrow y^{c-1}=\left(\frac{(y+99)^c}{y+999}\right)$
plugging in $y=x+1$ back into equation,
$\Rightarrow (x+1000)(x+1)^{c-1}=(x+100)^c$
Note: Knowing nothing much about the behaviour of c does not get me any further than this, hope this helps.

What is happening in the first step? log is not linear

Thanks for pointing out

If we assume that $c$ is "large", decent approximations are given by the $[n,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ of the lhs, the simplest being
$$P_1=\frac{111 (2 x+467)}{22 x+15037}$$
Suppose $c=10$; the above gives $x=49266.5$ while the solution is $x=49267.5$
May be, you xould prefer
$$P_2=\frac{111 \left(112210 x^2+88001447
   x+8764408357\right)}{11 \left(112210
   x^2+138495947 x+36574593757\right)}$$ which gives the result
